# SQL Server Agent Job step is not getting executed

Tags: sql-server

I have written sql agent job that has 2 steps. First step is executing another job which deletes text file from some location and second step  is copying specific file and pasting it to some location. If I execute these two steps independently they execute properly. However when I run it as a job, only first step gets executed , second does not. Job history is shows as Success. So it seems second step is also getting executed but is is not performing any action. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Check your job. On the steps tab, you can determine what happens when a step passes or fails. Sounds like step 1 is set to complete job with success, not run step 2.

Comment: Not really. On success of first step is stating it to go to next step and failing also does the same thing. For second step only I am quitting job with success or failure status.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the job history with the messages expanded